# zend framewrok error Invalid controller specified on production

Tags: zend-framework

I have strange issue with Zend. its working fine on localhost and development machine. but on production it gives error  Invalid controller specified (receipt)

```
Request Parameters:
array (
  'controller' => 'receipt',
  'action' => 'create',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

my application .ini is

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view[] = 

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that file with controller code is uploaded? And did you change the directories structure on production machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a case-sensitivity issue. Make sure the filename of the controller begins with a capital letter (ReceiptController.php) and the directory names are lowercase (modules, controllers).

Comment: ahh great.. it was controller file name title was not capital. not sure how is it working on local.

Answer (score 0):

try delete this line:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

If it still doesn't work, try my configs below (for multiple modules only):

```
resources.modules[] = ""
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV
```

*I'm sorry i speak English not well*